# How do I trick QGIS's map composer into chopping off the 000's in UTM coordinates?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

In QGIS 2.8 (ubuntu), you can create a map with ticks and labels. I want the first two digits to be smaller sized, the next 3 to to be normal sized, and hide the last 3 digits. QGIS does not offer this feature directly.

I tried to hide the last 3 digits by creating a custom projection. I just changed +units=m to +units=km. This seemed to work in the main screen, but the CRS behaves like the original CRS in map composer. I don't know if this is user error or a bug in QGIS. Maybe I just have to dive further into custom CRS and change 1.0s to 0.001s (or the other way) until it works?

Furthermore, I would like to get just the first 2 digits. If I run cs2cs -lu, a kilometer is the longest metric distance. Can I add a unit for 1000 kilometers? Or do I need to dig further into the sub-definitions?

Finally, is it possible to define a coordinate system that just displays the middle digits? Instead of dividing by 1000, I want to get the remainder instead.